# keyError: 'ba' when using setDefault method

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

So I'm basically trying to put a dictionary in a dictionary using the setdefault method.

```
text = 'banana'
k = 2

st = {}
circ_text = text + text[:k]
for i in range(len(circ_text) - k):
    kgram = circ_text[i:i + k]
    next_char = circ_text[i + k]
    st[kgram].setdefault(next_char, 0)
    st[kgram][next_char] += 1
print(st)
```

I'm trying to get something like this

```
st = {ba : {a : 1}
      an : {a : 2}
      .......
     }
```

For some reason I'm getting a keyError: 'ba'. So I'm I supposed to put 'ba' in the st dict before doing this? or is there way of adding the 'ba' key in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to support dynamic generation of `dict` entries at both levels. For this particular case, it's probably easiest to use a `defaultdict` for at least one of the levels (and since you're counting things, a `Counter` for the inner `dict`).

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

text = 'banana'
k = 2

st = defaultdict(Counter)
circ_text = text + text[:k]
for i in range(len(circ_text) - k):
    kgram = circ_text[i:i + k]
    next_char = circ_text[i + k]
    st[kgram][next_char] += 1
print(st)
```

That simplifies your code (no explicit handling of missing keys), though it does mean your output will not just use `{}` wrapping. If you want it to look like nested `dict`s at the end (and/or need to stop auto-vivifying keys as `defaultdict` and `Counter` do), you'd add:

```
st = {k: dict(v) for k, v in st.items()}
```

before the `print` and that would convert back to plain `dict` of `dict`s.

Answer (score 0):

You never add new keys to `st`, so it is empty.

You are trying to access `st['ba']` and use its `setdefault` method, as if `st['ba']` is a dictionary, but `st['ba']` does not exist.

Perhaps you wanted to use `st.setdefault` instead, and set the default value for `st['ba']`:

```
st.setdefault(kgram, {})
st[kgram].setdefault(next_char, 0)
st[kgram][next_char] += 1
```

or:

```
st.setdefault(kgram, {next_char: 0})
st[kgram][next_char] += 1
```

Comment: So like st.setdefault(kgram, {next_char : 0})  ?

Comment: @JuanPabloEnrique Oh, yes, you can do that.

Comment: @JuanPabloEnrique: Downside to that is that it constructs a lot of temporary `dict`s; `setdefault`'s second argument is always constructed (even if it turns out to be unnecessary), so doing this means constructing a ton of one-element `dict`s (most of which are thrown away, assuming the `kgram`s repeat frequently). `defaultdict` (and `Counter`) avoid this by constructing the value on demand rather than preconstructing the default every time.